# how to get a title of a webpage using php?

Tags: php, html

I wrote the following code to get the title of a webpage. But the code doesn't work and output this error message: `Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string`

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://mysmallwebpage.com/");
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');

foreach ($links as $title)
{               
    echo (string)$title."<br>";
}
```

Could you please show me with an example?

Comment: `echo (string)$title."<br>";` needs to be `echo $title->nodeValue."<br>";`

Comment: @crypticツ Thanks a lot for the helpful information. I really appreciate it.